# jQuery datatables Twitter/facebook style paging

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have been searching around for a good resource on how to do this with no luck. I am using the jQuery datatables plugin with serverside processing along with pipelining enabled([example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html)). I have this working in my asp.net webforms project and will be moving to MVC for future projects. I am taking care of server side processing with the class found [Here](http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/01/19/jquery-datatables-plugin-meets-c.aspx). I have also been looking through the article found [Here](http://joelabrahamsson.com/entry/twitter-style-paging-with-aspnet-mvc-and-jquery) related to the pagination.

Basically what I need to do is create this type of pagination with the datatables plugin and server side processing(pipelining is not necessarily important here)

**NOTE:**
By twitter/style paging I am referring either to:

- A single button at the bottom of the table that brings back additional results appended to the existing content in the table
- Additional results loading infinitely as the user reaches the end of the current results via scrolling(NOTE: I have discovered that this functionality is built into the datatables plugin so I need to focus on the previous method).

Ultimately I would like to have the choice between both styles of pagination above.

Doest anyone have any good advice and/or samples/tutorials to share?

Comment: Did this ever get figured out?  I have the same issue two years later.

Comment: The best thing you can do is to make it from scratch. Its good to use libraries/plugins but later on if you want to update, it will be hard for you.
Goodluck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have developed [PageLoadMore](https://github.com/gyrocode/jquery-datatables-pageLoadMore) plug-in that allows to replace default pagination control with "Load more" button.

1. Include  plug-in's JavaScript file after loading jQuery and jQuery DataTables files.
2. Add "Load more" button with ID `btn-example-load-more` after the table.
3. Use the code below to initialize the table:

   ```js
   $(document).ready(function (){
      var table = $('#example').DataTable({
         dom: 'frt',
         ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
         drawCallback: function(){
            // If there is some more data
            if($('#btn-example-load-more').is(':visible')){
               // Scroll to the "Load more" button
               $('html, body').animate({
                  scrollTop: $('#btn-example-load-more').offset().top
               }, 1000);
            }

            // Show or hide "Load more" button based on whether there is more data available
            $('#btn-example-load-more').toggle(this.api().page.hasMore());
         }      
      });

      // Handle click on "Load more" button
      $('#btn-example-load-more').on('click', function(){  
         // Load more data
         table.page.loadMore();
      });
   });
   ```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/1bn6cza1) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: "Load more" button](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-load-more-button/) for more examples and details.

Comment: getting error will u plz help: Uncaught TypeError: this.api(...).page.hasMore is not a function
    at a.fn.init.drawCallback
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-pageLoadMore/1.0.0/js/dataTables.pageLoadMore.min.js"></script>