# Lazy loading of table rows in Jquery datatables 1.10.10?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatable 1.10.10. Is there any options for lazy loading of row data in datatable. For example , if the datatable contains 50 row of records,  if I scroll the datatable till the end, it requests for another 50 rows of data and appends to already existing datatable ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lazy loading can be achieved with [Scroller](http://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/) extension and server-side processing, see [Scroller - Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/server-side_processing.html) example.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        serverSide: true,
        ordering: false,
        searching: false,
        ajax: '/path/to/script',
        scrollY: 200,
        scroller: {
            loadingIndicator: true
        }
    } );
} );
```

Alternatively I have developed [PageLoadMore](https://github.com/gyrocode/jquery-datatables-pageLoadMore) plug-in that allows to replace default pagination control with "Load more" button. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45418674/3549014) or [jQuery DataTables: "Load more" button article](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-load-more-button/) for more examples and details.

Comment: Thank you . I will try this and let you know :)